# ASP.Net MVC Handling Segments with Route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, action, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to ASP.Net MVC and facing a problem. Here it is.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SearchResults",// Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{category}/{manufacturer}/{attribute}",
    new { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "CategoryProducts", 
        category = UrlParameter.Optional, 
        manufacturer = UrlParameter.Optional, 
        attribute = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

And here is my controller method.

```
public ActionResult CategoryProducts(string category, string manufacturer, string attribute) 
{
    string[] categoryParameter = category.Split('_');
    .
    .
    .
    return View();
}
```

when i hit the url i always get null in category parameter

```
http://localhost:50877/Home/CategoryProducts/c_50_ShowcasesDisplays
```

I get this error

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

How can i fix this problem. I need to extract the id from segment and use it. Similarly i need to process the manufacturer and attribute strings too.

One more thing

How can i make my function get at least one parameter regardless of order? I mean i want to make functions like that i can handle category or manufacturer or attributes or category + manufacturer and all the combinations/

Comment: Only the last parameter can be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional` (otherwise the routing engine cannot match up which is which). In order to make your current implementation work, you will need to use `http://localhost:50877/Home/CategoryProducts?category=c_50_ShowcasesDisplays`

Comment: thanks for the reply but i want to use segment instead of query string

Comment: Then you will need multiple routes and methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A placeholder (such as `{category}`) acts like a variable - it can contain any value. The framework must be able to understand what the parameters in the URL mean. You can do this one of three ways:

1. Provide them in a specific order, and for a specific number of segments
2. Put them in the query string so you have name/value pairs to identify what they are
3. Make a series of routes with literal segments to provide names to identify what the parameters are

Here is an example of option #3. It is a bit involved compared to using query string parameters, but it is certainly possible as long as you provide some sort of identifier for each route segment.

## IEnumerable Extensions

This adds LINQ support for being able to get every possible permutation of parameter values.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    // Can be used to get all permutations at a certain level
    // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n#1898744
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
    {
        return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
            elements.SelectMany((e, i) =>
            elements.Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat(c)));
    }

    // This one came from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774457/combination-generator-in-linq#12012418
    private static IEnumerable<TSource> Prepend<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource item)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        yield return item;

        foreach (var element in source)
            yield return element;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Permutations<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        var list = source.ToList();

        if (list.Count > 1)
            return from s in list
                   from p in Permutations(list.Take(list.IndexOf(s)).Concat(list.Skip(list.IndexOf(s) + 1)))
                   select p.Prepend(s);

        return new[] { list };
    }
}
```

## RouteCollection Extensions

We extend the `MapRoute` extension method, adding the ability to add a set of routes to match all possible permutations of the URL.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

public static class RouteCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void MapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string url, object defaults, string[] namespaces, string[] optionalParameters)
    {
        MapRoute(routes, url, defaults, null, namespaces, optionalParameters);
    }

    public static void MapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string url, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces, string[] optionalParameters)
    {
        if (routes == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("routes");
        }
        if (url == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
        }
        AddAllRoutePermutations(routes, url, defaults, constraints, namespaces, optionalParameters);
    }

    private static void AddAllRoutePermutations(RouteCollection routes, string url, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces, string[] optionalParameters)
    {
        // Start with the longest routes, then add the shorter ones
        for (int length = optionalParameters.Length; length > 0; length--)
        {
            foreach (var route in GetRoutePermutations(url, defaults, constraints, namespaces, optionalParameters, length))
            {
                routes.Add(route);
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Route> GetRoutePermutations(string url, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces, string[] optionalParameters, int length)
    {
        foreach (var combination in optionalParameters.Combinations(length))
        {
            foreach (var permutation in combination.Permutations())
            {
                yield return GenerateRoute(url, permutation, defaults, constraints, namespaces);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Route GenerateRoute(string url, IEnumerable<string> permutation, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces)
    {
        var newUrl = GenerateUrlPattern(url, permutation);
        var result = new Route(newUrl, new MvcRouteHandler())
        {
            Defaults = CreateRouteValueDictionary(defaults),
            Constraints = CreateRouteValueDictionary(constraints),
            DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary()
        };
        if ((namespaces != null) && (namespaces.Length > 0))
        {
            result.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = namespaces;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static string GenerateUrlPattern(string url, IEnumerable<string> permutation)
    {
        string result = url;
        foreach (string param in permutation)
        {
            result += "/" + param + "/{" + param + "}";
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);

        return result;
    }

    private static RouteValueDictionary CreateRouteValueDictionary(object values)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = values as IDictionary<string, object>;
        if (dictionary != null)
        {
            return new RouteValueDictionary(dictionary);
        }
        return new RouteValueDictionary(values);
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            url: "Home/CategoryProducts", 
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "CategoryProducts" }, 
            namespaces: null, 
            optionalParameters: new string[] { "category", "manufacturer", "attribute" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

This adds a complete set of routes to match the URL patterns:

```
Home/CategoryProducts/category/{category}/manufacturer/{manufacturer}/attribute/{attribute}
Home/CategoryProducts/category/{category}/attribute/{attribute}/manufacturer/{manufacturer}
Home/CategoryProducts/manufacturer/{manufacturer}/category/{category}/attribute/{attribute}
Home/CategoryProducts/manufacturer/{manufacturer}/attribute/{attribute}/category/{category}
Home/CategoryProducts/attribute/{attribute}/category/{category}/manufacturer/{manufacturer}
Home/CategoryProducts/attribute/{attribute}/manufacturer/{manufacturer}/category/{category}
Home/CategoryProducts/category/{category}/manufacturer/{manufacturer}
Home/CategoryProducts/manufacturer/{manufacturer}/category/{category}
Home/CategoryProducts/category/{category}/attribute/{attribute}
Home/CategoryProducts/attribute/{attribute}/category/{category}
Home/CategoryProducts/manufacturer/{manufacturer}/attribute/{attribute}
Home/CategoryProducts/attribute/{attribute}/manufacturer/{manufacturer}
Home/CategoryProducts/category/{category}
Home/CategoryProducts/manufacturer/{manufacturer}
Home/CategoryProducts/attribute/{attribute}
```

Now when you use the following URL:

```
Home/CategoryProducts/category/c_50_ShowcasesDisplays
```

The action `CategoryProducts` on the `HomeController` will be called. Your category parameter value will be `c_50_ShowcasesDisplays`.

It will also build the corresponding URL when you use `ActionLink`, `RouteLink`, `Url.Action`, or `UrlHelper`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("ShowcasesDisplays", "CategoryProducts", "Home", 
    new { category = "c_50_ShowcasesDisplays" }, null)

// Generates URL /Home/CategoryProducts/category/c_50_ShowcasesDisplays
```