# How to remove question marks in Asp.net MVC routes multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I pass multiple parameters to a controller action, I get question marks in the parameters like this:

http://localhost:57728/Home/AddAndManageProperties?BaseCategoryId=11&SubCategoryId=14

I want to remove the question marks to be like this:

http://localhost:57728/Home/AddAndManageProperties/BaseCategoryId=11/SubCategoryId=14

here is my code:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "MyRout",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{BaseCategoryId}/{SubCategoryId}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AddAndManageProperties", BaseCategoryId = UrlParameter.Optional, SubCategoryId = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );


    }
}
```

And here is the Action Method:

```
 public ActionResult AddAndManageProperties(int? BaseCategoryId, int? SubCategoryId)
        {
        }
```

And i call the method AddAndManageProperties by this method

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddSubCategory(SubCategory subCategory)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("AddAndManageProperties", new { BaseCategoryId = subCategory.BaseCategoryId, SubCategoryId = subCategory.SubCategoryId });
}
```

I am new to ASP.NET MVC so please help me!

Comment: First you need to remove `BaseCategoryId = UrlParameter.Optional, SubCategoryId = UrlParameter.Optional` - only the last parameter can be optional. Then if you change it to `url: "Home/AddAndManageProperties/{BaseCategoryId}/{SubCategoryId}",` and move it before the default route it will work assuming your method has matching parameter names.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you so much for your help :) Can you please kindly write the code so i can understand it ... sorry i am very new in mvc. Thank you

Comment: First edit your question to include the signature of your `AddAndManageProperties()` method, and show how your generating the url (I assume your using `@Html.ActionLink()`?

Comment: And how are you generating the url - using `@Html.ActionLink()` or is this a `<form>` (with `FormMethod.Get`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I edit the question again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115586/discussion-between-lucia-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `MyRout` to be before the `Default` route and change it to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyRout",
    url: "Home/AddAndManageProperties/{BaseCategoryId}/{SubCategoryId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AddAndManageProperties" }
 );
```

Note that only the last parameter can be marked `UrlParameter.Optional` so the method needs to be

```
public ActionResult AddAndManageProperties(int BaseCategoryId, int SubCategoryId)
```

for the above route, or

```
public ActionResult AddAndManageProperties(int BaseCategoryId, int? SubCategoryId)
```

if you modify the above route definition to

```
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AddAndManageProperties", SubCategoryId = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Note, if you also want to include the text "BaseCategoryId" and "SubCategoryId" in the route, use

```
url: "Home/AddAndManageProperties/BaseCategoryId/{BaseCategoryId}/SubCategoryId/{SubCategoryId}",
```

Comment: It's working Thank you so much :) 
It's 
http://localhost:57728/Home/AddAndManageProperties/14/17

Can i make it like this ?
http://localhost:57728/Home/AddAndManageProperties/BaseCategoryId/14/SubCategoryId/17

Comment: Sure - Just change it to `url: "Home/AddAndManageProperties/BaseCategory/{BaseCategoryId}/SubCategory/{SubCategoryId}",` (and when you put url's in comments, surround it with backticks :)

Comment: Thank you but i tried this and is not working 
   url: "Home/AddAndManageProperties/BaseCategory/{BaseCategoryId}/SubCategory/{SubCateg‌​oryId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AddAndManageProperties" }

Comment: Yes now it's working :) Thank you so much Stephen :) God bless you :)

Answer (score 0):

That question marks are used for query strings, and they are required because this is how data is assigned to parameters your actions expect. You should not try to remove them, but you could use the [FromBody] attribute, not to send the parameters in query string.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, and most importantly, your routes are in the wrong order and you have multiple possible URLs that result in calling the wrong route. See [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674633/181087) for an explanation.

Secondly, [routes cannot contain more than one `UrlParamter.Optional`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx/).

Third, the `=` sign is only valid within a query string, [unless it is encoded](http://www.werockyourweb.com/url-escape-characters/). But IMO, you should [not use unsafe characters in a URL](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/) to avoid all of the headaches that come with them. A better alternative in this case would be to replace the `=` with a `-`.

Finally, if you want to truly make the parameters optional, one approach is to [provide multiple routes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32479803/181087) that allow the parameters in certain routes but not others.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
              name: "BaseCategoryAndSubCategoryId",
              url: "{controller}/{action}/BaseCategoryId-{BaseCategoryId}/SubCategoryId-{SubCategoryId}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AddAndManageProperties" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BaseCategoryIdOnly",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/BaseCategoryId-{BaseCategoryId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AddAndManageProperties" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SubCategoryIdOnly",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/SubCategoryId-{SubCategoryId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AddAndManageProperties" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

> **NOTE:** [Stephen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38028539/181087) is also a good alternative to this approach if your parameters are **required** to be passed in the URL. IMO, it makes more sense to use required parameters if your action method requires both of them in order to function.

But by far the simplest option is to simply use the query string. The parameters can naturally be optional and appended in any order if you do it that way, and you don't need anything more than your `Default` route.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I just saw your answer right now.. it's working too. God bless you :)