# How can i use second routedata value if there is

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, url-routing, query-string

I am using asp.net routing with one variable without problem but i want to use two variable and second variable is not must. It can be or it can't be.

Want to use routes:

```
products/{a}/{id}
services/{b}/{id}
```

In this case i must enter "a" variable and "id" variable to reach url. But i want to open url if there is no {id} varible like:

```
products/{a}
services/{b}
```

If i delete {id} from url in routing, the url above is working properly.

I have tried to add {*id} and opened but get conflict when you're opening pages. There is a solution i have found with {id?} but causes an routing error. Any suggestion?

**MY SOLUTION:**

I have added a new route to solve this problem. It's not the best but working. If you have much better solution with same route please share with us.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Products", "products/{a}", "~/products.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Services", "services/{b}", "~/services.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Productsid", "products/{a}/{id}", "~/products.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Servicesid", "services/{b}/{id}", "~/services.aspx");
```

Comment: What error it throws when you add {id?}? And are you using Asp.Net Web API / ASP.NET MVC app?

Comment: it's an asp.net webform project. it says "A route named 'mainpage' is already in route collection. Route names must be unique." and when i delete {id?} everything is works fine. I am using MapPageRoute for routing do i need to change with MapRoute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can make your {id} parameter optional by adding a rule:

```
    routes.MapPageRoute(
       routeName: "Products",
       routeUrl: "products/{a}/{id}",
       physicalFile: "~/products.aspx",
       checkPhysicalUrlAccess: true,
       defaults: new RouteValueDictionary(new {
       id = UrlParameter.Optional,
    });
```

Here is [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808698/mappageroute-cant-send-empty-strings-in-the-middle) which can help your more to get to your idea.